# Compare string datetime with ISO datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to compare ISO DateTime with string datetime in Python code. I am getting datetime in JSON response from Azure Cloud which I need to compare to the last 24 hours before datetime. I am stuck at string-to-datetime conversion.

Here is the code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

target_date = datetime.now() - timedelta (hours=24)
print(target_date.isoformat())
print(type(target_date))

createdOn = "2022-10-25T21:41:27.2824196Z"
post_time = datetime.strptime(createdOn, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(post_time)
```

I need to compare/check if createdOn is greater than target_date. While running the code, I am getting below error

```
    2023-08-07T13:22:11.914140
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/GitHub/Mylabs/mytest.py", line 10, in <module>
    post_time = datetime.strptime(createdOn, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2022-10-25T21:41:27.2824196Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to use [`python-dateutil` form PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) to do the date parsing.  This will parse the vast majority of known date formats and get things a little easier for you.

Once installed in PyPI, it can easily be used like so:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

# Done by answerer for easier reference in code.
from dateutil.parser import parse as dateparse

target_date = datetime.now().astimezone(timezone.utc) - timedelta (hours=24)
print(target_date.isoformat())
print(type(target_date))

createdOn = "2022-10-25T21:41:27.2824196Z"
post_time = dateparse(createdOn)
print(post_time)
```

Effectively, it takes the headache of parsing manually out of the equation so that you *know* it will parse the datetime format properly and "just work" with varying formats of timestamps.  While it doesn't solve your `strptime` issue it makes it easier to parse dates and timestamps.  (This is just *one* of the many things that `dateutil` can do, but it does this very well)

Since `dateutil`'s parser function returns a datetime object you can actually compare the two `datetime`s directly.  However, you should make sure that your time for target_date is `datetime.now.astimezone(timezone.utc)` (which is why timezone is in the imports) to make sure you are comparing two timezone aware `datetime`s.

Then you can compare them directly.

`print(target_date > post_time)` for example will print a boolean value if `target_date` is later than or equal to `post_time`.

---

Python 3.11 and later have a `fromisoformat` mechanism for easier conversion, however if you are using anything earlier (like Python 3.8), using `dateutil` will be the superior parser method.